# How do I clone with Git?

Tags: git, github, init

I am an absolute beginner with Git and clone. So I cloned a Git repository (see picture). But where is the folder, where can I see the content?

[image: Git]

Comment: Seems that the operation failed, see here in the error log.

Comment: Tip: Instead of posting an image you have to redact, just copy-paste the text and edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very useful command:

> ls -a

It shows the content of the current directory.

You've tried to clone your repository two times in a row, so the main directory of your repository already exists. You'd better delete it using next command:

> rm -rf MXDial-IoT-Sample

And then you can clone your repository once again with **git clone**.

If you want to "find the folder", use **ls**.

To change the current directory to your repository use:

> cd MXDial-IoT-Sample

To open it:

> explorer .

Comment: Explorer? Assuming Microsoft Windows?

Answer (score 1):

In your directory Git is already initialized, delete the `.git` directory in your project root folder. If not shown, enable hidden files in strings.

Comment: How does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
mv MXDial-IoT-Sample MXDial-IoT-SampleBAK
```

And then:

```
git clone https://github.com/Microsoft/MXDial-IoT-Sample.git
```

Comment: I did that. So where can I find the folder? Sry I am such a beginner

Comment: How does this help?